# How can i create a new file using FileStream without overwriting existing?

Tags: c#, filestream

I am creating an xml file using the following:

```
string filename = string.Format("MyXMLFile{0}-{1}", Id, Name);
try
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename + ".xml", FileMode.Create);
    using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(fs, new UTF8Encoding()))
    {
       //write xml data here
    }
}
catch (exception ex)
{

}
```

The issue is that this code is called from else where in a for loop and the filename could be the same name in some situations.
Is there a way I can tell the FileStream that if the filename exists , dont overwrite but create a new one ?

for example if the filename is TestXmlFile.xml then next round create TestXmlFile(1).xml and the next is TestXmlFile(2).xml

Comment: You may want to clarify that new code you've added *is not* an answer (clearly you shouldn't edit in an answer into a question) but rather a faulty attempt to resolve the problem on your own.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator suggestion works . FileMode.CreateNew does not . answering the question ? No was meant to be an update .. wrong click

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx):

> FileMode.Create

Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten

So, i would check first if file exists using

> File.Exists(FILE_PATH)

and
use a counter or a Timestamp(i believe this is approach is much better) to create the new one.

Comment: Feel free to ignore the second part of the answer - checking for file existence *does not* prevent the problem of reusing the same file name as it is a separate operation and file name could be used between check and opening the file. The first part is actually a good reference to the answer (unfortunately nether link-only answers nor suggesting to RTFM is not acceptable, otherwise I'd recommend check `FileMode.CreateNew`)

Comment: CreateNew I dont think will  work because it specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten.

Comment: No - with `FileMode.CreateNew` you will get an exception if the file already exists. You can then e.g. incremennt a counter variable that is part of the file name and try again until it succeeds.

Comment: @Kristy You looked at the wrong part of the documentation: that's the specification for `Create`, not `CreateNew`.

Comment: not sure what you mean .. I couldnt get CreateNew to work so i checked if file exists and if so added timestamp

Comment: @Kristy No matter if it exists or not. I would use a timestamp as a suffix of the file name. you dont need extra effort to implement it. Does it make sense ?

Comment: yep got it and that is what i did , as per your suggestion . I use a time stamp of  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") , so cant run in the same minute. Is there a more efficient way ?

Comment: sweet, based on your question that option is really useful lets say one day you grab a file and file name will give you aditionalinfo(creation) also it will avoid duplicated names.

Comment: I have gone even further and used DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss"). Thanks.